# Selection of best VARX model using VAR() in R

Tags: r, time-series, model-selection, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I have 9 variables (all stationary) grouped into five different datasets (each set has 4 common variables and one different). How can I evaluate which is the best VARX model? I'm using `VAR()` from the `vars` package to estimate the coefficients.

Is it correct to use log likelihood? Is there documentation of that? or should I look at the $R^2$ of each equations?

Note: I want to use the model to estimate the impulse response function.

Comment: How can you compare models with different dependent variables? Are you interested in only the four variables that are common? What is your criterion of a good/better model? You mention both VAR and VARX; which model are you working with, and what are the X variables?

Comment: I'm trying to find out which data set generates a better model to explain changes in my variables (I'm especially interested in one of my variables, let's call it A). I am working with VARX models, in the financial field, my variable X is the FED interest rates.

What I want to know is if there is a way to compare models with different dependent variables

Comment: I am not sure why anyone would be interested in comparing models for different dependent variables. What would it mean to say that ARMA(1,1) works better for $Y_1$ than ARMA(2,2) for $Y_2$? $Y_2$ might be fundamentally harder to forecast, so perhaps we have an ideal model for $Y_2$ that delivers apparently poorer predictive performance than a mediocre model for $Y_1$, just because $Y_1$ is so much more predictable. If you are interested in FED interest rate, I would look at how well the different models are able to predict it out of sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in FED interest rate, I would look at how well the different models are able to predict it out of sample, namely, what is the expected loss from the (one-step-ahead) forecast errors from the different models. This can be estimated either (1) directly by using time series cross validation or (2) indirectly by taking in-sample loss and adjusting it for model complexity. E.g. AIC offers an indirect estimate of the expected loss defined as twice the negative log-likelihood.

(However, taking AIC of an entire VAR model is not what you want, as that would reflect the models' ability to predict not only the FED interest rate but also all other dependent variables. What you want instead is the AIC of the equation for the FED interest rate alone. You could obtain it by specifying the single equation for the FED interest rate.)